# Setting up custom scheme using @DataJpaTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, h2, jpa-2.1

I want to test a Repository with Spring Boot and want to include TestEntityManager to check that the repository really does what it should do.

That's the JUnit Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class MyRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;

    ...
```

For the other JUnit tests I have an application-junit.properties file that sets up a schema with some tables, indexes, sequences and constraints:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;Mode=Oracle;INIT=create schema if not exists testdb\\;SET SCHEMA testdb\\;runscript from 'classpath:create.h2.sql';
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true

#datasource config
spring.database.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.database.jndi-name=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Now, with DataJpaTest this configuration does not seem to be used. Even if I add @ActiveProfiles("junit").

How can I make the JUnit test use my create.h2.sql file to set up the tables?

Thanks in advance,
Nina

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It isn't because `@DataJpaTest` replaces [your configured datasource by an in-memory data source](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test).

If you don't want that, which is clearly the case with that `junit` special profile, you need to instruct Spring Boot not to override your configureed `DataSource`. There is an example in the doc in the link I gave above. Essentially, your test should look like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("junit")
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)
public class MyRepositoryTest {
   ...
}
```

You should consider creating a meta-annotation to share the last two (three?) annotations so that you don't have to repeat this over and over again.